# Suffling in Listview For Music player

Tags: android, arrays, android-music-player

I am making a music player where I placed a shuffle `Button`.

```
case R.id.ib3:
    // long s1=System.nanoTime();
    setSuffle(); // its is a function just ignore this
    Collections.shuffle(index);
    newlist(); // its is a function just ignore this
    listView.setAdapter(new Song_Adapter(this,al_new));
```

My songs are added in `ArrayList` and I am passing that `List` to my custom adapter and set it to the `ListView`.

I want to achieve a shuffle of the list with index, so that when I click on the shuffled list, the song should be play according to new index.

**Edit** from comment:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int l, long m) {
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle(); 
    bundle.putInt("id",y); 
    Intent i=new Intent(this,Second.class); i.putExtras(bundle);      
    //startActivity(i); 
    // globle.setSong_id(l);
    startService(i); }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to set a new `Adapter` to the `ListView`. Keep a reference to your adapter and call `notifyDataSetChanged();` on it.

```
//above onCreate, declare:
private MyCustomAdapter adapter;


//set the adapter ONCE, the first time you need it: 
adapter = new Song_Adapter(this,al_new);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);

//call this everytime your dataset has changed:
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Get a random song:

```
int randomIndex = new Random().nextInt(mySongList.size());
```

Comment: thats ok but how to suffle the song according to index. The problem is when i click on the song in the list view after suffling. only name change in tyextview but index does not changes

Comment: I can't understand what you are trying to achieve. Could you describe your problem..? Is the wrong song (not the clicked) played? If so, please share your code where you handle the list click

Comment: `enter code here`  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int l, long m)
    {

>        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt("id",y);
        Intent i=new Intent(this,Second.class);
        i.putExtras(bundle);
        //startActivity(i);
     //   globle.setSong_id(l);
        startService(i);
    }

Comment: what is `y`? From where do you get it? If this should be the position of your clicked song, you should pass `l`, like `bundle.putInt("id", l); `

Comment: I added a line on how to  get a random song.

Answer (score 0):

You need to shuffle your ArrayList first and then use **notifyDataSetChanged();**

```
private Song_Adapter songAdapter;

     @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    case R.id.ib3:
         shuffleMySongs();
    break;

    }

     private void shuffleMySongs(){

      //to shuffle your arraylist
        Collections.shuffle(yourArrayList);

      songAdapter = new Song_Adapter(this, yourArrayList);
      songAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
      listView.setAdapter(songAdapter);

    }
```

Comment: public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int l, long m)
    {

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt("id",l);
        Intent i=new Intent(this,Second.class);
        i.putExtras(bundle);
        //startActivity(i);
     //   globle.setSong_id(l);
        startService(i);
    }    how to suflle the index i mean variable v...

Comment: i got the solution on my own but thanks for help  :)

Comment: Then please post your solution as an answer and accept it, to mark your question as solved :)